# Query is instant when hardcoding value and doesn't finish otherwise

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

I have a query that is instant when hard-coding a value in the WHERE clause but when using the value from a joined table the query just never finishes.

I cannot figure out why as I cannot even view the execution plan since the query doesn't finish. I mean it makes sense that it would take longer when it has to look at a table's record instead of a hard-coded value but not THIS much longer.

I have this temp-table setup:

```
#MY_TEMP_TABLE -- PRIMARY KEY (district_id asc, school_id asc, class_id asc)

school_id | class_id | end_dte (int) | district_id
--------------------------------------------------
1         | 5        | 20201223      | ABC


HISTORY TABLE -- PRIMARY KEY (end_dte asc, class_id asc, school_id asc)

school_id | class_id | end_dte (int)
------------------------------------

CLASS TABLE -- PRIMARY KEY (class_id asc, school_id asc)

school_id | class_id | district_id
----------------------------------
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT HT.school_id, HT.class_id, MAX(HT.end_dte)
FROM HISTORY_TABLE HT
INNER JOIN CLASS C ON HT.school_id = C.school_id AND HT.class_id = C.class_id
INNER JOIN #MY_TEMP_TABLE MTT ON C.school_id = MTT.school_id AND C.class_id = 
MTT.class_id AND C.district_id = MTT.district_id
WHERE C.district_id = 'ABC'
AND HT.end_dte <= MTT.end_dte
GROUP BY HT.school_id, HT.class_id
```

I have 1 record right now inside of #MY_TEMP_TABLE and HISTORY_TABLE has millions across different school_id and class_id values.

If I hard-code a specific value in place of MTT.end_dte in the WHERE clause the query finishes instantly.

Comment: In SSMS you could always check [estimated exection plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Please give DDL for the other tables. Any reason you're not joining on district_id which seems to be part of PK?

Comment: Updated query showing proper join on district_id. @Charlieface
And added other table info.

Comment: DDL means the `CREATE TABLE` statement with all indexes. If those are the only indexes, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Looks like the index on `HISTORY_TABLE` should have the `end_dte` column last. Can you add an execution plan via [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: I do not have access to the execution plan. Yes those are the only indexes (primary keys).

Comment: If you are running outside SSMS, you can grab the plan with this `SET STATISTICS XML ON;` before your query. The plan will be a second resultset (`NextResult()` in C#). Did you try switching the index columns?

Comment: I cannot change the indexes. But yes the query seems to be instant when testing with an index with end_dte at the end. 

I’ve found that some data also processes instantly using CROSS APPLY and SELECT TOP 1 instead of using MAX. But then other parameters begin to take long to process. Using OPTION RECOMPILE worked for 1 set of parameters but not all.

Comment: It seems like with the lack of an index, trying to find the MAX date when the closest match is many days away is what causes it to be so slow.